# Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy Font

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I am using W3 Total Cache with Amazon cloudfront. I have in my htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN W3TC CDN
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END W3TC CDN
```

But still getting error:

Font from origin 'https://example.cloudfront.net' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://www.example.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 8):

Found the solution in this link: https://www.naschenweng.info/2014/09/23/wordpress-w3-total-cache-cloudfront-font-cors-issue/.

You need to change the CloudFront distribution's behaviors settings:

- Change “Forward Headers” from “None” to “Whitelist”
- Add “Origin” to the “Whitelist Headers”
- Make sure that “Use Origin Cache Headers” is checked

Then invalidate the cached fonts.

Comment: Just wanted to stress that invalidating the cached fonts was a crucial step for me to fix this.

Answer (score 4):

Wrestling with this for days, and think I finally fixed it. Here are some things to check:

- The **webserver** config should add the proper header. Apache syntax is listed in the question. Here's Nginx syntax that I used:

`location ~* \.(eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$ {
       add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*';
    }`

- Within **W3TC** > Performance > CDN > Custom File List, I added the following to upload the actual font files:

`{plugins_dir}/*.ttf
{plugins_dir}/*.woff`

- While you're there, set the **Theme file types to upload** to the following. Per @Yao's link, the default separators are inconsistent (should all be semicolons, not commas)

`*.css;*.js;*.gif;*.png;*.jpg;*.ico;*.ttf;*.otf;*.woff;*.less`

- In S3 > Permissions > CORS Configuration, change the default

`<AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>`

to:

`<AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>`

You should start seeing the necessary `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response.

- In CloudFront > Distribution > Behaviors, make the following changes:

  1. Change **Allowed HTTP Methods** to `GET, HEAD, OPTIONS` (you need `OPTIONS`)
  2. Change **Forward Headers** to **Whitelist**
  3. Under **Whitelist Headers**, **Add** >> **Origin**
- To test:

`curl -I -s -X GET -H "Origin: www.example.com" https://abcdefg543210.cloudfront.net/wp-content/path/to/foo.ttf`

This should give you back the following header:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront`

I found this blog post to be pretty helpful:
http://blog.celingest.com/en/2014/10/02/tutorial-using-cors-with-cloudfront-and-s3/

Comment: I think in your S3 settings only `<AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>` is significant.

Comment: `<AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>` is sufficient to return the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` HTTP header from the S3 backend.

Answer (score 2):

basicly It's because the font isn't set to be shared outside of the domain that you are on, so you can just use it as a resourse for, in this case, https://example.cloudfront.net

This can be changed in the webserver settings though.

Comment: Can you explain? I've got the same problem. I did set the CORS on S3 bucket to allow for any origin, any headers, yet still the font doesn't load on Chrome. What do I change in the webserver settings?

Answer (score 0):

The problem may not always be with the origin settings on Nginx or Apache at your web server end.

You will also need to enable CORS on your S3 AWS account for this to work correctly.